# How to put the heading "MyRide" along with the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I tried several options, im still learning html and css. I was unable to find answer here, so i thougt to add this. Help is much appreciated.

this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyRide|Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/new.css"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="cover-image heading">
            <header>
                <img src="../images/headerLogo.png" alt="logo" width="25%" height="10%">MyRide
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul id="ul1">
                    <li class="navbar"><a href="./home.html" class="li1">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar"><a href="./fleet.html"class="li1">Fleet</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar"><a href="./services.html"class="li1">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar"><a href="./about.html"class="li1">About</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar"><a href="./contact.html"class="li1">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>              
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the css code

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:darkgray;
    flex: 10;
}

.cover-image{
    background-image: url(../images/headercover.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-color: black;
    
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.heading{
    color: red;
    font-size: 90px;
}

a.li1{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gold;
}

header,nav{
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar{
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin:0;
}
#ul1{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    align-content: end;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

this is what i see,
[green line is how i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5raf.png)

it seems like the UL is the one makingg the new line after the heading but i couldn't find a way to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use flexbox.  Makes positioning really easy.  Look into display:flex, align-items: and justify-content:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:darkgray;
    flex: 10;
}

.cover-image{
    background-image: url(../images/headercover.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-color: black;
    
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

.heading{
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}

a.li1{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gold;
}

header,nav{
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar{
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin:0;
}
#ul1{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    align-content: end;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyRide|Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/new.css"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="cover-image heading">
            <header>
                <img src="http:\\placeholder.com/50" alt="logo" width="25%" height="10%">MyRide
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul id="ul1">
                    <li class="navbar"><a href="./home.html" class="li1">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar"><a href="./fleet.html"class="li1">Fleet</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar"><a href="./services.html"class="li1">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar"><a href="./about.html"class="li1">About</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar"><a href="./contact.html"class="li1">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>              
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you intended something like this, it can be achived with `flexbox` trinity. Generally, child container placing relationships within parent container is managed by `flexbox` and `grid`, quite easily by the way!

```css
.cover-image {
  background-image: url(../images/headercover.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  /*flexbox trinity*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```